# nagios as standalone monitoring server

Tags: nagios

Is there a way to install and run NAGIOS monitoring server in Ubuntu 12.04 as standalone ? I don't want to use apache or nginx as the front end to serve nagios. is it possible ?
I googled, but couldn't find any tutorial or blogs.

Comment: Guys, before choosing "close" option, please read the points carefully "http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic"
My question comes under this category. So blindly choosing some choice, doesn't make sence. If you don't know the answer, then leave it
"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you do not want to install Web UI for Nagios, then skip the Web UI installation [steps](http://ahmermansoor.blogspot.com/2016/08/nagios-core-42-installation.html). i.e. 
make install-webconf

Then use a Desktop Monitoring Tool like 'Nagastamon' for Monitoring.